# why myPyQt5 project Update picture display in real time

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
    import os
    path_of_image = './some_file.png'
    import sys
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QWidget,QLabel,QPushButton
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
    
    
    class App (QtWidgets.QWidget):
        def __init__(self):
            super ().__init__ ()
            self.initUI ()
    
    
    
    
            # threading.Thread (target=self.initUI (), args=()).start ()
            # threading.Thread (target=self.update_image(), args=()).start ()
    
        def initUI(self):
    
    
                QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)
                QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps, True)
                # QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents ()
                self.w_ = QtWidgets.QMainWindow ()
                self.w_.resize (512, 360)
    
    
                self.w_.setWindowFlags (QtCore.Qt.SplashScreen | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
                self.w_.setAttribute (QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
                self.w_.setStyleSheet ("background:transparent;")
    
                self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel (self.w_)
    
    
                self.label.setGeometry (QtCore.QRect ( 615,292, 200, 200))
    
                self.label.lbl = QLabel ("photo", self.label)
                self.label.pm = QPixmap ("./some_file.png")
    
    
                self.label.lbl.setPixmap (self.label.pm)
                self.label.lbl.resize (200,200)
    
                self.w_.showFullScreen ()
                timer = QtCore.QTimer (self)
                timer.timeout.connect (self.update_image)
                timer.start (1000)
                # time.sleep(10)
    
                #self.update_image ()
    
    
    
        #
        def update_image(self):
            #
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap (path_of_image)
            try:
                if not pixmap.isNull ():
                    QApplication.processEvents ()
    
                    print(pixmap.isNull ())
                    self.label.pm = QPixmap ("./some_file2.png")
                    self.label.setPixmap (self.label.pm)
                    self.label.adjustSize ()
                    print( QPixmap ("./some_file2.png"))
                    self.resize (pixmap.size ())
                    self.w_.showFullScreen ()
            except Exception as err:
                    print ('An exception happened: ' + str (err))
    
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication (sys.argv)
        ex = App ()
    
        sys.exit (app.exec_ ())
```

This is my code ,but i don't Realize Refresh photo

I tried to use Qtimer to implement time slots and multithreading, but none of them achieved the effect I wanted-refreshing the picture in real time (in my transparent borderless background),If you use Qtime and multithreading, you may encounter the following situations where thread congestion causes the Qt window to become unresponsive.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtNetwork
from pyzbar import pyzbar as pyzbar
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QWidget,QLabel,QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
class Loader (QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__ (parent)
        manager = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager()
        manager.finished.connect (self.onFinished)
        self._manager = manager

    def start(self, url, label):
        self._url = url
        self._label = label
        self.request()

    def request(self):
        manager = self._manager
        req = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(QtCore.QUrl(self._url)) #todo:
        res = manager.get (req)

    def onFinished(self, reply):
        data = reply.readAll()
        self.w_ = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.w_.resize (512, 360)

        self.w_.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.SplashScreen | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.w_.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.w_.setStyleSheet("background:transparent;")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.w_)

        self.label.setGeometry (QtCore.QRect (615, 292, 200, 200))

        self.label.lbl = QLabel("qrcode", self.label)
        self.label.pm = QPixmap("./some_file.png")

        self.label.lbl.setPixmap (self.label.pm)
        self.label.lbl.resize(200, 200)
        self.label.pm.loadFromData(data)
        self._label.setPixmap(self.label.pm)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.request)
        self.w_.showFullScreen()
if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        label.show()
        loader = Loader()
        url = "http://172.17.135.67:5421/api/download?filename=/some_file2.png"
        loader.start(url, label)
        app.exec()
```

I wrote a refresh function of my QR code based on the example of others, but his work was wrong and there were two windows showing pictures.

Comment: First of all, QTime is a class for time representation, so either you meant QTimer instead, or you used the wrong class for the wrong purpose. Then, widgets are not thread-safe, so you shall never access them from external threads; similarly, also QPixmaps cannot be created in external threads. Finally, even ignoring the above, the argument of a thread's `target` is a *callable*, which is the reference to a function, while you're using the parentheses, meaning that you're calling those functions, so they're **not** executed in a thread, and they completely block your program.

Comment: sorry,I know very little about PyQt5. These implementation methods are all introduced on the Internet. Do you have any better ideas to achieve this amount of update refreshing photos Function ?

Comment: Sincerely, it's not really clear what you're actually trying to achieve: what do you mean with "refreshing the picture in real time"? Besides, please don't put spaces between function names and their parentheses, it's just terrible to read.

Comment: My goal is to constantly update the pictures from the folder / server on my Qt interface to ensure that they are up to date. For example, I need to update a QR code on my interface in real time to ensure the security of the user's QR code.

Comment: Then just use QTimer. Note that: 1. it's unclear what would be the use of `App`, since you're never showing it; 2. you should not directly add widgets as children of a QMainWindow: you either use `setCentralWidget()` or you use a basic QWidget instead; 3. as the [documentation clearly says](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#setAttribute), most application attributes must be set **before** creating the QApplication, so you shouldn't certainly do it inside a QWidget constructor.

Comment: I updated my code for updating pictures in the qt5 interface in real time, but his expected function is still wrong. What should I do?

Comment: In your updated code there is absolutely no "thread congestion" (since there is no multithreading). It's just wrong since you're creating a new window every time you get the file, which clearly doesn't make any sense. It's actually unclear what you're *really* trying to do, as your code is very inconsistent (for instance, what's the point of resizing a window and making it frameless, if you're then showing it full screen? and what's the use of the first label, since you're hiding it with the window above?). Just use *one* window, put a label into it, and keep updating *that* label.